# What is the meaning of "it is to..."

Tags: meaning, dummy-it

What is the meaning of *it is to* in the following:

> *It is to* the Director [of Central Intelligence] that the assistant first turns to learn the facts in a crisis and for analysis of events, and since decisions turn on the perception of the consequences of actions the CIA assessment can almost
>   amount to a policy recommendation.

Comment: Please see also: [ell.se]

Answer (score 3):

It is a way to put emphasis on a particular element in a sentence, to focus the reader's attention on it. The attention is attracted to the main clause in the beginning of the sentence.

Technically there's no need for two clauses in such sentences, they could be remodeled back to a one-clause form. You can read up on the topic in Wikipedia's "[cleft sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleft_sentence)" article.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine:

> It is *to you* that he will give his millions at the end of this year.

Would that make you happy, or puzzled? Does *it is to* make more sense there?

*It is to* is a style of saying *This is to whom* (he leaves his millions/the assistant first turns. Simply:

> In a crisis, the assistant first turns **to** the Director [of Central Intelligence] to learn the facts...

Answer (score 0):

The phrase that begins the sentence could be rewritten in a way that is easier to understand. Instead of:

> "It is to the Director [of Central Intelligence] that the assistant first turns to learn..."

this would be clearer if the writer had said:

```
The assistant first turns to the Director to learn...
```

Some writers feel beginning a sentence with "It is.." is clumsy, and can lead to readers misunderstanding the focus of the sentence. In this case, it confuses the subject and the object by putting the object "the Director" first, and the subject, "the assistant" last. In English, that switch can be considered awkward, and it tends to confuse readers that are not familiar with the language's conventions.